# How to copy files to the User's setting folder in the Visual studio Setup project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, deployment, installation

How can I specify files in the Setup Project in Visual studio that should be copied to the C:\Documents and Settings\User foder, where User is the name of the user installing my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `USERPROFILE` environment variable. It points to the full path of the current user profile. You have to use a [custom action type 51](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368237.aspx) to copy it into a property so that it can be used as the target folder for installing files.

I'd recommend using either AppData folder for this purpose:

- [**`AppDataFolder`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367565.aspx) is the full path of the *roaming* folder for the current use
- [**`LocalAppDataFolder`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369768.aspx) is the full path to the file system directory that serves as the data repository for *local (non-roaming)* applications.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout this link [UserFolder / Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369768%28VS.85%29.aspx)